# Div style changing using asp.net C# code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, styles

```
<div runat="server" class="labels" style="display:none; height: 100%; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">
     <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Description:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Impact:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Recommendation:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br /><br />
</div>
```

I want to change style to display:true as it is know on display: none and i want to done it using c# code. how to call class name and change its style/attributes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give an id to your div like this

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"></div>
```

And then in your C# code write this to add style to div.

```
string style = div1.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display];

if(style.ToLower()=="none")
   div1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");
```

And here is how you can remove style.

```
div1.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display);
```

Comment: But also need to add check if `div1` has `display : none`. If yes then add this code `div1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");`

Comment: i want to remove display:none from style

Answer (score 0):

```
<% var display = "block"; 
   if(isHidden){
       display = "none";
   }
%>

<div runat="server" class="labels" style="display:<%=display%>; height: 100%; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">
     <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Description:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Impact:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Recommendation:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <br /><br />
</div>
```